# Why does OpenCV not compile with ffmpeg support?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I ran the following command to compile opencv:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/user/work/repo/venv/local/ -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/Users/user/work/repo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/user/work/repo/venv/bin/python -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/ffmpeg -D FFMPEG_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib64 -D WITH_FFMPEG=YES ..
```

Which resulted in:

```
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.75.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.63.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.45.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.3.101)
--       avresample:                NO
```

Then any Python call to opencv using ffmpeg as a capture source will fail.

I though I had the proper paths setup, since calling the ffmpeg command line returns:

```
$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version n3.0.5-19-ga71d22d-rpmfusion Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/local/bin/ --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --extra-cflags='-O2 -g' --extra-version=rpmfusion --enable-bzlib --enable-nonfree --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --arch=x86_64
```

And looking up in those dirs indeed give me the list of codecs listed in the cmakeoutput.

I'm on OSX Sierra, and both opencv and ffmpeg are compiled manually.

I can run the ffmpeg command line fine to convert any video file I need. I also can fire a Python shell and import using opencv and opening videos works correctly as long as I used the default capture source instead of cv2.CAP_FFMPEG. This means I can only open mp4 files right now.

Comment: to compile you may need source code of ffmpeg or at least headers files `*.h` - maybe there is `ffmpeg-dev` packages with .h files only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to follow this tutorial, compiling opencv with python virtualenv path lead to error for some obscur reasons.

I installed opencv without setting the virtualenv python path then copied the cv2.so file to virtualenv python path and all worked magically.

I can't explain why but now I can read videos without extension in any supported formats.

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install opencv3 --with-ffmpeg
```

Depending on your needs you may add options `--with-python3` and/or `--with-contrib`.

To list all available options run

```
brew info opencv3
```

Comment: brew install opencv3 lead to no pkgconfig error or something similar, don't remember the exact error, I was not able to make it works even with brew reinstall pkg-config.